# Generate all 4-tuple pairs from n elements

Tags: python, algorithm, combinatorics

I would like to generate a list of all possible **4-tuple pairs** given an array of size `n`. `n` is at least 8, so it is always possible to find at least 1 pair.

As an example that helps to understand the problem I use a smaller version of the problem, **2-tuple pairs** given an arrayy of size `5`. The expected result for 2-tuple pairs would result in 15 items (tuples are ordered, no duplications):

`[(1,2), (3,4)], [(1,2), (3,5)], [(1,2), (4,5)], [(1,3), (2,4)], [(1,3), (2,5)], [(1,3), (4,5)], [(1,4), (2,3)], [(1,4), (2,5)], [(1,4), (3,5)], [(1,5), (2,3)], [(1,5), (2,4)], [(1,5), (3,4)], [(2,3), (4,5)], [(2,4), (3,5)], [(2,5), (3,4)]`

My current way in doing this is to use `itertools` from python and go through all elements returned by `itertools.combinations`, do 2 loops and find 2 pairs that do not share a single element and then work with that element.

To express this in python code I prepared a small snippet:

```
arr = list(range(30)) # example list 
comb = list(itertools.combinations(range(0, len(arr)), 4))

for c1 in comb:
    for c2 in comb:  # go through all possible pairs
        if len([val for val in c1 if val in c2]) == 0:  # intersection of both sets results in 0, so they don't share an element
            ... # do something and check for duplicates
```

This method is doing its job, but is inefficient due to the 2 loops and only works for small `n` in a given timeframe. Can this be done more efficient?

---

Update: After some answers I evaluated the suggestions. The best thing for my specific case is the (extended) algorithm provided by the (now deleted) answer of MSeifert, which performs the fastest:

```
def generate_four_pairs(n):
    valids = range(0, n)
    for x00, x01, x02, x03, x10, x11, x12, x13 in itertools.combinations(valids, 8):
      yield [x00, x01, x02, x03], [x10, x11, x12, x13]
      yield [x00, x01, x02, x10], [x03, x11, x12, x13]
      yield [x00, x01, x02, x11], [x03, x10, x12, x13]
      yield [x00, x01, x02, x12], [x03, x10, x11, x13]
      yield [x00, x01, x02, x13], [x03, x10, x11, x12]
      yield [x00, x01, x03, x10], [x02, x11, x12, x13]
      yield [x00, x01, x03, x11], [x02, x10, x12, x13]
      yield [x00, x01, x03, x12], [x02, x10, x11, x13]
      yield [x00, x01, x03, x13], [x02, x10, x11, x12]
      yield [x00, x01, x10, x11], [x02, x03, x12, x13]
      yield [x00, x01, x10, x12], [x02, x03, x11, x13]
      yield [x00, x01, x10, x13], [x02, x03, x11, x12]
      yield [x00, x01, x11, x12], [x02, x03, x10, x13]
      yield [x00, x01, x11, x13], [x02, x03, x10, x12]
      yield [x00, x01, x12, x13], [x02, x03, x10, x11]
      yield [x00, x02, x03, x10], [x01, x11, x12, x13]
      yield [x00, x02, x03, x11], [x01, x10, x12, x13]
      yield [x00, x02, x03, x12], [x01, x10, x11, x13]
      yield [x00, x02, x03, x13], [x01, x10, x11, x12]
      yield [x00, x02, x10, x11], [x01, x03, x12, x13]
      yield [x00, x02, x10, x12], [x01, x03, x11, x13]
      yield [x00, x02, x10, x13], [x01, x03, x11, x12]
      yield [x00, x02, x11, x12], [x01, x03, x10, x13]
      yield [x00, x02, x11, x13], [x01, x03, x10, x12]
      yield [x00, x02, x12, x13], [x01, x03, x10, x11]
      yield [x00, x03, x10, x11], [x01, x02, x12, x13]
      yield [x00, x03, x10, x12], [x01, x02, x11, x13]
      yield [x00, x03, x10, x13], [x01, x02, x11, x12]
      yield [x00, x03, x11, x12], [x01, x02, x10, x13]
      yield [x00, x03, x11, x13], [x01, x02, x10, x12]
      yield [x00, x03, x12, x13], [x01, x02, x10, x11]
      yield [x00, x10, x11, x12], [x01, x02, x03, x13]
      yield [x00, x10, x11, x13], [x01, x02, x03, x12]
      yield [x00, x10, x12, x13], [x01, x02, x03, x11]
      yield [x00, x11, x12, x13], [x01, x02, x03, x10]
      yield [x01, x02, x03, x00], [x10, x11, x12, x13]
      yield [x01, x02, x03, x10], [x00, x11, x12, x13]
      yield [x01, x02, x03, x11], [x00, x10, x12, x13]
      yield [x01, x02, x03, x12], [x00, x10, x11, x13]
      yield [x01, x02, x03, x13], [x00, x10, x11, x12]
      yield [x01, x02, x10, x00], [x03, x11, x12, x13]
      yield [x01, x02, x10, x11], [x00, x03, x12, x13]
      yield [x01, x02, x10, x12], [x00, x03, x11, x13]
      yield [x01, x02, x10, x13], [x00, x03, x11, x12]
      yield [x01, x02, x11, x00], [x03, x10, x12, x13]
      yield [x01, x02, x11, x12], [x00, x03, x10, x13]
      yield [x01, x02, x11, x13], [x00, x03, x10, x12]
      yield [x01, x02, x12, x00], [x03, x10, x11, x13]
      yield [x01, x02, x12, x13], [x00, x03, x10, x11]
      yield [x01, x02, x13, x00], [x03, x10, x11, x12]
      yield [x01, x03, x10, x00], [x02, x11, x12, x13]
      yield [x01, x03, x10, x11], [x00, x02, x12, x13]
      yield [x01, x03, x10, x12], [x00, x02, x11, x13]
      yield [x01, x03, x10, x13], [x00, x02, x11, x12]
      yield [x01, x03, x11, x00], [x02, x10, x12, x13]
      yield [x01, x03, x11, x12], [x00, x02, x10, x13]
      yield [x01, x03, x11, x13], [x00, x02, x10, x12]
      yield [x01, x03, x12, x00], [x02, x10, x11, x13]
      yield [x01, x03, x12, x13], [x00, x02, x10, x11]
      yield [x01, x03, x13, x00], [x02, x10, x11, x12]
      yield [x01, x10, x11, x00], [x02, x03, x12, x13]
      yield [x01, x10, x11, x12], [x00, x02, x03, x13]
      yield [x01, x10, x11, x13], [x00, x02, x03, x12]
      yield [x01, x10, x12, x00], [x02, x03, x11, x13]
      yield [x01, x10, x12, x13], [x00, x02, x03, x11]
      yield [x01, x10, x13, x00], [x02, x03, x11, x12]
      yield [x01, x11, x12, x00], [x02, x03, x10, x13]
      yield [x01, x11, x12, x13], [x00, x02, x03, x10]
      yield [x01, x11, x13, x00], [x02, x03, x10, x12]
      yield [x01, x12, x13, x00], [x02, x03, x10, x11]
```

For the general approach I would suggest the answer provided by NPE as this is the shortest and easiest readable answer for this problem.

Comment: What is `arr` and are you sure that `itertools` solution really works? Also why 15 elements and not 30? What is the problem with `[(4, 5) (2, 3)]` for example?

Comment: @MSeifert, it's equivalent to `[(2, 3), (4, 5)]` which is already in the list. "Tuples are ordered, no duplications".

Comment: But the `itertools` solution presented actually does give `[(4, 5), (2, 3)]` if `itertools.combinations(range(0, len(arr)), 4)` is replaced with `itertools.combinations(range(1, 6), 2)`, which is why I wondered if that solution works at all or correctly. It certainly doesn't currently if one assumes `len(arr)` to be `5`.

Comment: Yes, with the solution above there are also duplicates. They are filtered at the end since I do not know about an easier solution than filtering them at the end. Sorry about this misunderstanding

Comment: Still leaves the problem that `arr` isn't defined and `4` in `combinations` seems wrong because you want 2 2-tuples. But your approach would give 2 4-tuples.

Comment: I added more clarification to the text. I am indeed looking for 2 4-tuples. The example with 2 2-tuples is just so that I could fit the whole example here and keep it easier to understand. The definition of `arr` is not important here and the only important fact is that `len(arr)>=8` holds. I will add an example `arr` to the text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing a lot of unnecessary work by generating all pairs of combinations, and then discarding almost all of them because they contain common elements.

The following addresses this by first taking all subsets of four numbers (in your 2-tuple example), and then splitting each into all possible pairs:

```
import itertools

def gen_pairs(n, m):
  for both_halves in itertools.combinations(xrange(1, n + 1), 2 * m):
    for first_half in itertools.combinations(both_halves, m):
      second_half = tuple(sorted(set(both_halves) - set(first_half)))
      yield [first_half, second_half]

print sorted(gen_pairs(5, 2))
```

Note that this does not eliminate duplicates (for example, `[(4, 5) (2, 3)]` vs `[(2, 3), (4, 5)]`) and thus produces twice the number of elements you expect.

It is trivial to remove the duplicates, however. This is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Nice solution! Tip for the readers : only call `yield` if the first element of `first_half` is smaller than the first element of `second_half`

Answer (score 0):

You can use permutations and splitting which may be faster:

```
array = ...
size = 4
c = itertools.permutations(array)
for t in c:
    a = []
    for i in range(0, len(t), size):
        if i + size <= len(t):
            a.append(t[i:i+size])
    yield a
```

Note: In the case where the length of the array is not a multiple of the size this solution works but produces duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do:

```
from itertools import combinations

sample = range(1,6)
x1 = [subset for subset in combinations(sample,2)] #getting the set of tuples
x2 = [list(subset) for subset in combinations(x1,2)] #getting the pair of tuples
x3 = [x for x in x2 if (set(x[0]) & set(x[1]) == set())] #finally filtering the tuples with no intersection
```

Output:

```
[[(1, 2), (3, 4)],
 [(1, 2), (3, 5)],
 [(1, 2), (4, 5)],
 [(1, 3), (2, 4)],
 [(1, 3), (2, 5)],
 [(1, 3), (4, 5)],
 [(1, 4), (2, 3)],
 [(1, 4), (2, 5)],
 [(1, 4), (3, 5)],
 [(1, 5), (2, 3)],
 [(1, 5), (2, 4)],
 [(1, 5), (3, 4)],
 [(2, 3), (4, 5)],
 [(2, 4), (3, 5)],
 [(2, 5), (3, 4)]]
```

Answer (score 0):

And here's code to generate MSeifert's yield statements :) (And it only yields 35 of them, which means there are no duplicates :)

```py
def g(L, n, k, A, B):
    if len(A) == k:
        return [[tuple(A), tuple([L[i] for i in xrange(0, n + 1)] + B)]]

    elif len(B) == k:
        return [[tuple([L[i] for i in xrange(0, n + 1)] + A), tuple(B)]]

    return g(L, n - 1, k, A, [L[n]] + B[0:]) + g(L, n - 1, k, [L[n]] + A[0:], B)

def f(L):
    assert(len(L) > 3 and len(L) % 2 == 0)
    return g(L, len(L) - 2, len(L) / 2, [], [L[-1]])

for i in f(['x00','x01','x02','x03','x10','x11','x12','x13']):
    print(i)
```